# wordpress изменить html css

Tags: wordpress, cms

Так я сегодня задал вопрос и смог получить доступ к wp-admin(СМS). Так я сейчас хочу например изнутри js/css изменить. И слова и изображения а там в CMS нельзя много чего изменить помогите как и откуда это сделать

Comment: Открываешь страницу в браузере, на которой нужно что-либо изменить - смотришь в консоли какие файлы `.css` и `.js` подключаются - ищешь их в проекте, вносишь изменения.

Comment: а html/изображение? Из FTP захожу 3000+ файлов а то что файлы проекта ссам сайт html/css там хотел изменить html не понятно что все php т.д а из wp-admin не как не изменить

Comment: Аналогично найти изображение по коду страницы, которая генерируется, и заменить. `php`-скрипты также могут генерировать код разметки. Проще всего открыть в среде а-ля `PHPStorm`, там удобней искать нужные файлы и т. д.

Comment: Так мне не известна программа PHP-storm это для чего? И в среде чего вы сказали(Извините могу надоедать ну вы очень помогаете)

Comment: `PHPStorm` - среда для разработки web-проектов в частности.

Comment: Понял вас как только установлю скажу вам! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменять, а точнее писать свои css можно через кастомайзер - `сайт/wp-admin/customize.php` (=*внешний вид - настроить*) - Дополнительные стили.

Если же есть необходимость править файлы, то нужно использовать [механизм дочерних тем](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).
Править оригинальные файл тем, плагинов, а тем более [ядра](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) = потерять возможности обновления и риски поломать сайт насовсем.

Comment: В кастомайзере не все поменять можно а мне знаете именно что надо есть сайт и есть 3 языка. С языком англ файлы находятся en/themes т.д а версия сайта русского языка и английского очень отличаются(стили) хочу копировать стиль англ на русс и там слово/содержимое изменить

Comment: Через кастомазер можно поменять любые стили, если знать CSS. Остальной твой набор букв я неосил.

Comment: Понятно блогадарю

Answer (score 0):

В вордпресс есть понятие "темы" (оформление сайта). Все файлы темы находятся в папке `/wp-content/themes/название_темы/`. Структура файлов темы может быть почти любая, только обязательно есть несколько файлов:

`/wp-content/themes/название_темы/style.css` - файл стилей темы (может не использоваться на сайте, но в нем содержатся данные о теме),

`/wp-content/themes/название_темы/functions.php` - файл с возмозностями темы. Здесь происходит подключение скриптов и стилей на сайт системными функциями WP.

Ну естественно в папке темы должны быть файлы разметки (`index.php` минимум)

Comment: `functions.php` - не обязательный файл. https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC#.D0.91.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.88.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8B